# Neo4J: User-defined Procedure does not like Periodic Commit?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to develop a Neo4J procedure that imports nodes from a database, transforms them to CSV and loads them into a neo4j.

I keep being stuck with the following: Running the procedure as a unit test works fine. However, when I try to run the procedure in Neo4J Desktop, I keep getting  this exception:

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.QueryExecutionException: Executing stream that use periodic commit in an open transaction is not possible.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.QueryExecutionKernelException.asUserException(QueryExecutionKernelException.java:35)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureGDBFacadeSPI.executeQuery(ProcedureGDBFacadeSPI.java:147)
        ....
```

This happens when I call `db.execute(..)` on my `GraphDatabaseService` db.

The exact query looks like this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/nodes_Class.txt" AS cl 
MERGE (n:Class { iri: cl.iri})
```

If I run the exact same query by itself in Neo4J Desktop, all nodes are imported without a problem. Now I read that Periodic commits [can only be executed in "Auto-commit transactions"](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/sessions-transactions/). To ask it in a stupid fashion: How can I tell my procedure that it is allowed to execute periodic commits?

Comment: I replaced my answer, as I originally misread your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a plugin procedure, which requires the (non-Bolt) [Java API](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/). But the [documentation that you referenced](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/sessions-transactions/) is for the [Bolt Driver API](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/), which is completely different (yes, this can be a bit confusing).

Using the Java API (that is appropriate for plugins), you must invoke "USING PERIODIC COMMIT" clauses *outside* of a transaction.

So, instead of executing the Cypher code within a transaction like this:

```
try (final Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    db.execute( "USING PERIODIC COMMIT ..." );
    tx.success();
}
```

just execute it outside a transaction:

```
db.execute( "USING PERIODIC COMMIT ..." );
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks :) Now your answer explains the problem, but does not solve it: I was not using the PERIODIC COMMIT as part of a transaction so far; Now at least I know why it works when I execute the program as part of a unit test. However, the procedure should be usable as part of Neo4J Desktop, which, as far as I know, connects to the database through bolt; So do you know of a way I can do periodic commit generically, i.e. in a setting that sometimes involves connections through bolt (Neo4J Desktop) and sometimes not (cypher console)? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @matentzn did you ever solve this, I have the exact same problem with trying to use USING PERIODIC COMMIT

Comment: @K.Haydock Unfortunately not. I dont remember exactly, but I think I have replaced the entire code with a horrific "via-csv" workaround, using the GraphDatabaseApi. Something like 

```
String cypher = "USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000\n" +
                          "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM \"file:/" + fn + "\" AS cl\n" +
                          "MERGE (n:Entity { iri: cl.iri }) SET n += ...";
final Future<String> cf = exService.submit(()->{dbapi.execute(cypher); return "Finished: "+filename;});
System.out.println(cf.get());
```

Not sure why CSV anymore, tooo long ago.